# Magento 2: Class 'ObjectManager' not found

Tags: magento2

I have a cron to run to add to a given table in the database, here is the cron

```
<?php
    require_once 'Price.php';
    $cron=new \Managys\Pricing\Price();
    $cronGo = $cron->GetNewproduct();
```

?>

Class Price.php:

```
<?php
namespace Managys\Pricing;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class Price
 {
    function GetNewproduct()
   {
    $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('mp_new_products');
....
}
```

in order to call this cron I have an error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: [NEVER use ObjectManager](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html).

Back to your question, change

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
```

To

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
```

Reason: You are not under `Magento` namespace. You should add slash(\) before any class declarations in order to use core functions.